# Is there anyway to use a dropdown without sending a response in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, dropdown

I have made a dropdown select in discord.py but when the user selects an option i dont want to respond with a message but if i dont respond with a message i get "Interaction Failed" in discord.

```py
@commands.command()
    async def shop(self,ctx):
        em = discord.Embed(title = "Store",description = "Buy smthing", colour = ctx.author.colour)
        await ctx.send(embed = em,
        components=
        [
            Select(placeholder="Choose a item",
                                options=[
                                    SelectOption(
                                        label = "A",
                                        value = "a",
                                        description = ""
                                    ),
                                    SelectOption(
                                        label = "B",
                                        value = "b",
                                        description = ""
                                    ),
                                   

                                ]),
                                Button(style = ButtonStyle.blue, label="button 1")
                                
        ])

        def check(msg):
            return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel

        while True:
            try:
                res = await self.client.wait_for("select_option", check=check, timeout=10)
                label = res.values[0]
                
                await res.respond(content=f"U have clicked {label}") #If I don't write this line i get the message "Interaction failed"
                

                print(label)  #This was just for checking the output.
                break
            
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await ctx.send("Sorry, you didn't reply in time!")
                break
            except discord.NotFound:
                print("error")
```

I dont fully understand how dropdown works, can someone please explain how to go abt this.

For example dank memer doesnt send response when i click on a option.
[NO respones from bot when i clicked on the option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI2I7.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
res.edit_origin(content = "This message can be exactly the same as your original message")
```

This function does not send any message, but it does stop the interaction failed message to appear

You can also do the following to change the embed and buttons / select menu:

```
res.edit_origin(content = "just some random message",component =[newButtons],embed=EmbedObject)
```

BTW: The image in your question was done by disabling the message's button (basically editing the buttons).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
await interaction.response.defer()
```

will complete the interaction without the error

> This interaction failed'

This is especially helpful while doing edit messages or add roles to users without any output

Answer (score -1):

You must respond to a message when a dropdown is clicked. This is a Discord API limit.

Comment: But in a bot like dank memer there is a command to buy pet using "pls pet".
After choosing a pet from the dropdown the bot doesnt send any response, but still it works, how is that possible

Comment: It does send a response wdym?

Comment: No it doesn't i just checked. I updated my qn, i hv included the screenshot

Comment: It is indeed sending a message. Check out the [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/enh46Ly) I took. Maybe it is something on your end or something is wrong with the settings.

Comment: Yeah I get the message when i click on the "buy" button but, when i just click on an option in the dropdown, i get an error for my bot .(If i hadnt written the respond code"). Also can u please edit the code to make it behave like dank memer.

Comment: @Vinurk It does make a respond (it edits the message)

Answer (score -1):

There is a way but it isn't that clean:

````
@client.command(name='test')
async def text(ctx):

    global ctxn #make a global variable named for example ctxn
    ctxn = ctx #double the value from the ctx ;)

    global msgTest
    #Define the Fields you want to have in the Dropdown
    msgTest = await ctx.send(f'```Select a component```',components = [
                [Select(placeholder="Select Settings", 
                options=[SelectOption(label="Label1", value="Value1"), #Label is the Display Name, Value is for Interaction Selection
                         SelectOption(label="Label2", value="Value2"), 
                         SelectOption(label="Label3", value="Value3")])]
                ]
            )
@client.event
async def on_select_option(interaction):
#After the selection it searches for the value="XXXXX"
    if interaction.values[0] == "Value1":
        await msgTest.delete() #Here you delete the dropdown after you selected an entry
        await TEST1(ctx=ctxn) #Call the Function with the copied ctx start value

    if interaction.values[0] == "Value2":
        await msgTest.delete() #Here you delete the dropdown after you selected an entry
        await TEST2(ctx=ctxn) #Call the Function with the copied ctx start value

    if interaction.values[0] == "Value3":
        await msgTest.delete() #Here you delete the dropdown after you selected an entry
        await TEST3(ctx=ctxn) #Call the Function with the copied ctx start value

#Here you can programm your functions
async def TEST1(ctx): #First Function
    return await ctx.send("Function 1 were selected")

async def TEST2(ctx): #Second Function
    return await ctx.send("Function 2 were selected")

async def TEST3(ctx): #Third Function
    return await ctx.send("Function 3 were selected")
````

If you don't delete the dropdown menu which you sendet within the msgTest variable, you will still get the interaction failed msg.

Comment: Can you explain what you have done?

Comment: I added some more notes to the code, if you have a specific question don't hesitate to ask